# IB - Can't assign class for a View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I'm quite new to IOS developpement, and I'm facing a problem here that I haven't encountered before. Here's what I have :

I created a project, added some ViewControllers attached to their own classes. But now, I just added a new ViewController in the storyboard. Then I created a new Objective-C class (with is a subclass of UIViewController). The problem is that in IB, I can't link the ViewController to the newly created class, as I simply don't have the class in the list provided by IB (see the image below). My new class is called `MapShownViewController`, but as you can see on the image, it's not available.

[image]

It worked well for all my other classes but not for this one.

Here's the MapShownViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MapShownViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

And the MapShownViewController.m :

```
#import "MapShownViewController.h"

@interface MapShownViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapShownViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Can someone explain me what I made wrong please ?

Comment: `Map` is a terrible name for a view controller- now  `MapViewController` like in your list looks good

Comment: This was for the example, but thanks anyway for the tip !

Comment: could you add the code of map.h, please...?

Comment: @meronix There is nothing in it atm, just the default code created automaticaly when I create the file.

Comment: @Paul.s I changed it in the post to fit what I have in my project.

Comment: Even if there is nothing in it we still need to see at least the declaration of the interface to actually rule it out.

Comment: @Paul.s I've put the code generated after the creation of the file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this exact problem and it drove me mad. I first noticed it after upgrading XCode to 4.4 from 4.1. I had an existing project that I had been working on in the older version of XCode, and I continued to work on it in 4.4. I did exactly what you did and created a new View in the story board and then created the sub-class files, but the class just was not avaiable in the Custom Class dropdown in IB. After much Googling and frustration I resorted to Quit Xcode (complete quit, not just close) and then re-start it. Then as if by magic it all started working and the new class was immediatley available in the IB custom class dropdown.

Comment: That's just what I did, and indeed it was fixed !

Comment: That's great, glad you're sorted! I apprecaite it is a bit of an 'IT Call Centre' answer (close App and re-start) but it's the only consistent way I can make it fix that particular problem. I anyone can add value to how and why this fixes it then feel free, but until such a time, this is my fix.

Comment: Had the same issue. Seems to be a bug in the new Xcode release

Comment: +1 Works like a charm! Thanks, This is a really annoying xCode bug!

Comment: this  doesnt work for me. I tried in 4.3.3 and 4.6.2  In a project I developed in earlier than 4.2  now loses the custom class!! Machine setting?? When I create a new project it is fine until I add a toolbar  button or item to toolbar then it is gone no matter what!

Comment: Didn't work for me, tried restart, product->clean, everything. It only shows UITableViewController class as an option. Xcode 4.6, updating to 5, hope it really got fixed...

Comment: Yes, upgrading to Xcode 5 solved the problem. I think it might be my fault while creating the custom class, like described in a few other answers and simply adding it to the project correctly could have solved the problem, who knows.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I saved the project, quit xCode all together, and violâ it worked. This is great, but WHY does this happen? Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 18):

Ran into the same issue and restarting XCode was no help.  You can always right click the storyboard and select `Open As > Source Code`.  Find your view controller element in the XML file and add a `customClass` attribute:

```
<viewController title="Login" id="TJH-Bg-q4u" customClass="XYZLoginViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
   ...
</viewController>
```

Manual override FTW :).

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved my issue. Not sure how to make sure this doesn't happen repeatedy.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.  Restarting Xcode did make the custom class show up in the custom class dropdown, just not for the view controller that I wanted to change!  For some reason, this view controller would not allow me assign it a) from the drop down or b) by manually typing it in the field.  But it would for all of my other view controllers.  The particular view controller that I could not change was the only one with a nested nav controller, which was the only apparent difference to me.

Answer (score 4):

Check your project settings. xcode->targets->build phases->compile sources 
your viewcontroller's implemantation file must be added to this list.

Comment: I have the file, but it's not like the other files. I don't have the "... in [Project Name]" in front of it. How can this happen ?

Comment: try adding a new controller. it asks you to add the file to targets (project's and test's both) maybe you didnt check them. i am not sure. for this problem you can delete and add the implementation file in compile sources tab itself..

Comment: I've re-created it. I've checked the checkbox to add it to the project. It's now correctly in the compile sources. But I can't see it in the list :(

Comment: ok, you are on file's owner? if you are, be sure you write the view controller's name correctly, characters capitalized or not? and also maybe you can try to change the name of view controller. it is just assuming but maybe Map.h is a used object for XCode already. change it like MyMapViewController etc.

Answer (score 4):

For this to work you have to make sure of the following:

1) The element added to the storyboard is an **UIViewController**

2) The class you defined has the **UIViewController** as its superclass

```
@interface MapShownViewController : UIViewController
```

3) The Class is being correctly built in the project.

Comment: I've followed all theses steps. Everything is fine except that I still don't see the class in the list :s Could it be a more generic parameter that is not set correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into this issue and tried all other solutions posted here.

The thing that worked for me was to set the correct super class after creating a custom class. Then you should be able to find and select it from the class dropdown.

e.g.

```
class LabsViewController: UITableViewController {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you did choose the correct super class in your new class. Sometimes you create a view controller inherited by a UITableVIewController. This one can't be applied to a ViewController pattern in the Storyboard.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I do not see the new SubClass that I defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set my custom class which inherit from UIViewController and act as table view controller to UITableViewController. I made simple trick and just changed my custom class inheritance to ": UITableViewController" and then i can set this class freely to controller. Of course after it was set i changed inheritance back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Xcode 7.1.1 on a Mac OSX app. I tried all the suggestions from the other answers – no success.

Finally I deleted my view controller files and created brand new ones.
Then it suddenly worked...

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another possible solution that helped solve my problem since the others didn't.

I noticed that searching for my custom View Controller file using Command+Shift+O it was being found, but I couldn't see in which folder the file was, so I noticed that for some reason my custom class was missing from the project but still being found in the search.

All I had to do was to move the files to the project again and Voila!

Hope this can help someone in the future.